# Find the least number of points plotted on the circle .

Tags: summation, problem-solving, arc-length

So here is the Question :-

> In the figure, $AB = 200$ is a diameter of the circle. Points $A$,$B$ are given the numbers $1,1$. The two semi-circles are bisected at $C,D$. Numbers $2,2$ are given $C,D$. Each, of the quarter circles are bisected and given the number $3$.[image]
>
> Now each arc is bisected and the point is given the number which is the sum of the $2$ numbers at the endpoints of the respective arc. This process is the continued till the sum of all numbers on the
> circle is at-least numerically equal to the product of $4$ times the area of the circle and $\frac{1}{3}$rd the radius. Find the least number of points on the circle (Take $\pi$ to be $3.14$) .

**What I Tried** :- You can actually calculate the product of $4\pi r^2$ and $\frac{r}{3}$ , which comes out to be :- $$\frac{4\pi r^3}{3} \rightarrow \frac{4*3.14*1000000}{3} \rightarrow 4186666$$

Here $4186666$ is the numerical part which is the sum of all the numbers on each arcs of the circle . The question is, how do you get this sum, because there is no specific pattern I can observe between these numbers on the arcs?

Can someone help me?

Comment: The answer is not known to me , but maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't see the forest because you're too focused on the trees.  Add *all* the numbers up after each step -- 2, then 6, then 18, ... seems to triple each time.

When you make an iteration by bisecting arcs, the new sum counts each addend from the previous sum three times -- once from the earlier point, and once from each newly generated neighbor of that original point.  For example, when you generate the 4 and 5 elements, each 3 from the previous set is also counted as part of the adjacent 4 and part of the adjacent 5.

So the sum is $2×3^n$ where $n$ is the number of iterations after starting with $A$ and $B$.  In addition each bisecting doubles the count of points, as the number of arcs is also doubled.  Proceed from there.

Comment: Ok I think I get the idea, can I just know the meaning of an iteration?

Comment: You are doing the same thing (bisecting arcs) over and over again, each time you do it is an iteration.

Comment: Ok, so are we considering bisecting $1$ single arc as an iteration or bisecting all the possible arcs in the circle in each step an iteration?

Comment: Bisect all arcs from one step to get the next one.

Comment: Ok so I find the number of iterations to be $12$ , that's when it exceeds $4186666$ , but how do you find the number of points on the circle?

Comment: How many are there after each iteration?  Can you figure out how the count of points (as distinct from the sum of the numbers) is multiplied with each iteration?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113520/discussion-between-anonymous-and-oscar-lanzi).